# Magento 2 Configuration depends

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, system.xml, system-config

In my configuration, I have two field number x and number y. I want to add a condition in which the number y must be less than the number x. How can I write this condition in a configuration file (system.xml)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Js mixin to add a custom validation rule for your system config field as described below

**Step 1)** Create file **requirejs-config.js** under **/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/adminhtml/**

File: **/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/adminhtml/web/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/validation': {
                'Pritam_HideInfo/js/validation-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

step 2)  Create file **validation-mixin.js** under **/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/adminhtml/web/js**

File: **/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/adminhtml/web/js/validation-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";
    return function () {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-minimumage',
            function(value, element) {                
                 var xElemHtmlId = "Your Cofig field ID for X";// Plesae find id from View Source of the page
                 var xval =  $("#"+xElemHtmlId).val();                
                 xval = parseInt(xval);
                 //console.log("x value="+xval);
                 //console.log("Y value="+value);                 
                 return (value >= xval ? false : true);             
            },
            $.mage.__('Y must be less then number X')
        );
    }
});
```

step 3: You system.xml should have x and y fields

.............
.............

```
<field id="myconfigx" translate="X" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>X</label>
                    <validate>validate-number</validate>
                </field> 
                 <field id="myconfigy" translate="X" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Y</label>
                    <validate>validate-number validate-minimumage</validate>
                </field>
```

.............
.............

**step 4:** Remove static files using below commands

```
sudo rm -rf var/generation/* sudo rm -rf var/di/* sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessing/* sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* sudo rm
-rf var/pub/static/* sudo rm -rf var/cache/* sudo rm -rf var/generated sudo rm -rf var/composer_home sudo rm -rf var/page_cache sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* sudo rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/*
```

[image]